# Github repository directory structure

Tags: github

Is there a way to make sure certain files are in the top-level directory your github repository? I have only two files, a README and a JSON, and I just want to confirm they are in the top-level directory of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit your repo on GitHub and you see README and JSON files there without being in a directory, then it's confirmed, the files are in the top-level directory.

In general any git repo, and as a result a GitHub remote repo, they have the exact same structure as your local project. So if on your computer the files are on the top directory (i.e the top directory for git is the one that includes `.git` directory in it).

If you go to your local directory and run the following:

Linux/macOS:

```
ls -la
```

If you see `.git` directory in there then this is the git's top-level directory.